# Center div Vertical/Horizontal without flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
/**
 * tiltfx.js
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright 2015, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
;
(function(window) {

  'use strict';

  /**
   * **************************************************************************
   * utils
   * **************************************************************************
   */

  // from https://gist.github.com/desandro/1866474
  var lastTime = 0;
  var prefixes = 'webkit moz ms o'.split(' ');
  // get unprefixed rAF and cAF, if present
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame;
  var cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame;
  // loop through vendor prefixes and get prefixed rAF and cAF
  var prefix;
  for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
    if (requestAnimationFrame && cancelAnimationFrame) {
      break;
    }
    prefix = prefixes[i];
    requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame || window[prefix + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    cancelAnimationFrame = cancelAnimationFrame || window[prefix + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] ||
      window[prefix + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
  }

  // fallback to setTimeout and clearTimeout if either request/cancel is not supported
  if (!requestAnimationFrame || !cancelAnimationFrame) {
    requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
        callback(currTime + timeToCall);
      }, timeToCall);
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };

    cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
      window.clearTimeout(id);
    };
  }

  function extend(a, b) {
    for (var key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  // from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position
  function getMousePos(e) {
    var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
      posx = e.pageX;
      posy = e.pageY;
    } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
      posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    return {
      x: posx,
      y: posy
    }
  }

  // from http://www.sberry.me/articles/javascript-event-throttling-debouncing
  function throttle(fn, delay) {
    var allowSample = true;

    return function(e) {
      if (allowSample) {
        allowSample = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
          allowSample = true;
        }, delay);
        fn(e);
      }
    };
  }

  /***************************************************************************/

  /**
   * TiltFx fn
   */
  function TiltFx(el, options) {
    this.el = el;
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend(this.options, options);
    this._init();
    this._initEvents();
  }

  /**
   * TiltFx options.
   */
  TiltFx.prototype.options = {
    // number of extra image elements (div with background-image) to add to the DOM - min:1, max:5 (for a higher number, it's recommended to remove the transitions of .tilt__front in the stylesheet.
    extraImgs: 2,
    // the opacity value for all the image elements.
    opacity: 0.7,
    // by default the first layer does not move.
    bgfixed: true,
    // image element's movement configuration
    movement: {
      perspective: 1000, // perspective value
      translateX: -10, // a relative movement of -10px to 10px on the x-axis (setting a negative value reverses the direction)
      translateY: -10, // a relative movement of -10px to 10px on the y-axis 
      translateZ: 20, // a relative movement of -20px to 20px on the z-axis (perspective value must be set). Also, this specific translation is done when the mouse moves vertically.
      rotateX: 2, // a relative rotation of -2deg to 2deg on the x-axis (perspective value must be set)
      rotateY: 2, // a relative rotation of -2deg to 2deg on the y-axis (perspective value must be set)
      rotateZ: 0 // z-axis rotation; by default there's no rotation on the z-axis (perspective value must be set)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initialize: build the necessary structure for the image elements and replace it with the HTML img element.
   */
  TiltFx.prototype._init = function() {
    this.tiltWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    this.tiltWrapper.className = 'tilt';

    // main image element.
    this.tiltImgBack = document.createElement('div');
    this.tiltImgBack.className = 'tilt__back';
    this.tiltImgBack.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.el.src + ')';
    this.tiltWrapper.appendChild(this.tiltImgBack);

    // image elements limit.
    if (this.options.extraImgs < 1) {
      this.options.extraImgs = 1;
    } else if (this.options.extraImgs > 5) {
      this.options.extraImgs = 5;
    }

    if (!this.options.movement.perspective) {
      this.options.movement.perspective = 0;
    }

    // add the extra image elements.
    this.imgElems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.extraImgs; ++i) {
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.className = 'tilt__front';
      el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.el.src + ')';
      el.style.opacity = this.options.opacity;
      this.tiltWrapper.appendChild(el);
      this.imgElems.push(el);
    }

    if (!this.options.bgfixed) {
      this.imgElems.push(this.tiltImgBack);
      ++this.options.extraImgs;
    }

    // add it to the DOM and remove original img element.
    this.el.parentNode.insertBefore(this.tiltWrapper, this.el);
    this.el.parentNode.removeChild(this.el);

    // tiltWrapper properties: width/height/left/top
    this.view = {
      width: this.tiltWrapper.offsetWidth,
      height: this.tiltWrapper.offsetHeight
    };
  };

  /**
   * Initialize the events on the main wrapper.
   */
  TiltFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this,
      moveOpts = self.options.movement;

    // mousemove event..
    this.tiltWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        // mouse position relative to the document.
        var mousepos = getMousePos(ev),
          // document scrolls.
          docScrolls = {
            left: document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
            top: document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop
          },
          bounds = self.tiltWrapper.getBoundingClientRect(),
          // mouse position relative to the main element (tiltWrapper).
          relmousepos = {
            x: mousepos.x - bounds.left - docScrolls.left,
            y: mousepos.y - bounds.top - docScrolls.top
          };

        // configure the movement for each image element.
        for (var i = 0, len = self.imgElems.length; i < len; ++i) {
          var el = self.imgElems[i],
            rotX = moveOpts.rotateX ? 2 * ((i + 1) * moveOpts.rotateX / self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.height * relmousepos.y - ((i + 1) * moveOpts.rotateX / self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
            rotY = moveOpts.rotateY ? 2 * ((i + 1) * moveOpts.rotateY / self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.width * relmousepos.x - ((i + 1) * moveOpts.rotateY / self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
            rotZ = moveOpts.rotateZ ? 2 * ((i + 1) * moveOpts.rotateZ / self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.width * relmousepos.x - ((i + 1) * moveOpts.rotateZ / self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
            transX = moveOpts.translateX ? 2 * ((i + 1) * moveOpts.translateX / self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.width * relmousepos.x - ((i + 1) * moveOpts.translateX / self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
            transY = moveOpts.translateY ? 2 * ((i + 1) * moveOpts.translateY / self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.height * relmousepos.y - ((i + 1) * moveOpts.translateY / self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
            transZ = moveOpts.translateZ ? 2 * ((i + 1) * moveOpts.translateZ / self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.height * relmousepos.y - ((i + 1) * moveOpts.translateZ / self.options.extraImgs) : 0;

          el.style.WebkitTransform = 'perspective(' + moveOpts.perspective + 'px) translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px,' + transZ + 'px) rotate3d(1,0,0,' + rotX + 'deg) rotate3d(0,1,0,' + rotY + 'deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,' + rotZ + 'deg)';
          el.style.transform = 'perspective(' + moveOpts.perspective + 'px) translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px,' + transZ + 'px) rotate3d(1,0,0,' + rotX + 'deg) rotate3d(0,1,0,' + rotY + 'deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,' + rotZ + 'deg)';
        }
      });
    });

    // reset all when mouse leaves the main wrapper.
    this.tiltWrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(ev) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        for (var i = 0, len = self.imgElems.length; i < len; ++i) {
          var el = self.imgElems[i];
          el.style.WebkitTransform = 'perspective(' + moveOpts.perspective + 'px) translate3d(0,0,0) rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg)';
          el.style.transform = 'perspective(' + moveOpts.perspective + 'px) translate3d(0,0,0) rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg)';
        }
      }, 60);

    });

    // window resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', throttle(function(ev) {
      // recalculate tiltWrapper properties: width/height/left/top
      self.view = {
        width: self.tiltWrapper.offsetWidth,
        height: self.tiltWrapper.offsetHeight
      };
    }, 50));
  };

  function init() {
    // search for imgs with the class "tilt-effect"
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img.tilt-effect')).forEach(function(img) {
      new TiltFx(img, JSON.parse(img.getAttribute('data-tilt-options')));
    });
  }

  init();

  window.TiltFx = TiltFx;

})(window);
```

```css
.tilt {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tilt__back {
  position: relative;
}
.tilt__front {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.tilt__back,
.tilt__front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="megawrapper">
  <div class="w-section home-page" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
    <div class="home_logo" style="pointer-events:none;"></div>
    <div class="home_centralarea" data-ix="home-darkfield" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 500ms;">
      <div class="home_parallaxpic_wrapper">
        <div class="home_parallaxpic" data-ix="home-parallaxpic" style="opacity: 0.4; transition: opacity 1000ms;">
          <img class="hero__img tilt-effect" data-tilt-options='{ "extraImgs":3, "bgfixed":false, "opacity" : 0.5, "movement": { "perspective" : 1200, "translateX" : -5, "translateY" : -5, "rotateX" : -5, "rotateY" : -5  } }' src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/road.jpeg"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to replicate HTML structure of this website (www.danielspatzek.com/). But I cant get my divs to center properly. The website has two main divs, .home-page which contains the fully stretched background image and .tilt which injects the tiltfx effect on the background image. The div .tilt has a scaled down height/width due to a padding of 60px applied on it by its parent div .home-page

I replicated the HTML structure but when I apply the 60px padding in .home-page all divs get pushed right/down and is no longer centered.

The original website html is:

```
<div class="megawrapper">
  <div class="w-section home-page" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
      <div class="home_logo" style="pointer-events:none;"></div>
      <div class="home_centralarea" data-ix="home-darkfield" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 500ms;">
          <div class="home_parallaxpic_wrapper">
              <div class="home_parallaxpic" data-ix="home-parallaxpic" style="opacity: 0.4; transition: opacity 1000ms;">
                  <img class="hero__img tilt-effect" data-tilt-options='{ "extraImgs":3, "bgfixed":false, "opacity" : 0.5, "movement": { "perspective" : 1200, "translateX" : -5, "translateY" : -5, "rotateX" : -5, "rotateY" : -5  } }' src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/road.jpeg" />
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript file tiltfx.js removes .tilt-effect and replaces it with .tilt so the HTML is:

```
<div class="megawrapper">
        <div class="w-section home-page" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
            <div class="home_logo" style="pointer-events:none;"></div>
            <div class="home_centralarea" data-ix="home-darkfield" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0ms;">
                <div class="home_parallaxpic_wrapper">
                    <div class="home_parallaxpic" data-ix="home-parallaxpic" style="opacity: 0.4; transition: opacity 0ms;">
                        <div class="tilt"><div class="tilt__back" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://www.danielspatzek.com/themes/Theme/images/bg_home_street.jpg&quot;); transform: perspective(1200px) translate3d(0.787151px, -0.0129973px, 0px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -0.0129973deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0.787151deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My recreation HTML and CSS looks like this:

```
 <div class="megawrapper">
  <div class="home-page" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">  
    <img class="tilt-effect" data-tilt-options='{ "extraImgs":3, "bgfixed":false, "opacity" : 0.5, "movement": { "perspective" : 1200, "translateX" : -5, "translateY" : -5, "rotateX" : -5, "rotateY" : -5  } }' src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/road.jpeg" />
  </div>
```

```
        .megawrapper {
        position: absolute;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .home-page {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #3c3c3e;
        background-image: url(images/road.jpeg);
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .tilt {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .tilt__back {
        position: relative;
    }

    .tilt__front {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .tilt__back, .tilt__front {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
```

I cant seem to get the same layout as the website. I dont know why .tilt would not center properly when I apply padding of 60 px on .home-page. I dont want to use flexbox to achieve the same result

Comment: Can you create a **working** [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). It will much easier for us to help you that way.. Just what have you achived so far and what is the expected result. _One live demo is worth a thousand words_ :)

Comment: And why no flexbox?

Comment: @Aleks G Browser support is an issue for flexbox

Comment: @Mosh Feu i cant add the background image to the snippet. do you know how to add image

Comment: @Joseph I'm added an answer below,don't forget to tick it ,if it's useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ***box-sizing:border-box;*** on your **.home_page** it will work fine.I'm added the snippet below.

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
.home_page{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#3c3c3e;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy2w.jpg);
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding:60px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }
.tilt {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="home_page">
  <div class="tilt"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. To think one line of code had me pulling my hair for hours

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way.

```
<div class="divToCenterStuffIn">
    <div class="vertCenter">
         Vertical Center 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divToCenterStuffIn">
    <div class="horzCenter">
         Horizontal Center 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divToCenterStuffIn">
    <div class="trueCenter">
         True Center 
    </div>
</div>

.divToCenterStuffIn {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
}

.vertCenter
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top:50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.horzCenter
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.trueCenter {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```